90's/early 2000's movie - A group trapped in a huge building complex and trying survive traps
Made in the US.
The group consisted of a few adults, teenagers and a kid or two. The villain appears to be a young adult/teen with blonde hair, and wears a full body suit and mask colored black (and speaks to the group in a deep voice through a voice changer).

One scene that I remember the most is one of the group members (an elderly man with a mustache) is killed in this manner: His feet are sliced clean through a wire (I think) and falls to the ground. Then a small robot thing with a faux-friendly voice appears with a drill attached. It then strikes the man with its drill straight to his eye and kills him. This takes place in the buildings parking area.
The same robot who killed the elderly man is then destroyed by one of the woman member through fire.
The surviving members then escape through the sewers and jump to the sewers exit, I think by the sea or lake.


Marked as a duplicate as I'm pretty sure you're after Subterano (2003). If it's not the right one, let me know.

That is the one, yes. Many apologies !

No need to apologize. :) This is a good question and we have thousands of ID Qs, so it's hard to tell which ones are duplicates sometimes.

OP has confirmed this as a duplicate of What's name of movie where teenagers die in real life if they died in virtual reality?.

It seems unhelpful as an archive to mark drastically different Q's as dupe just because they lead to the same answer. 1 + 1 should not be a dupe of 3 - 1.

@MeatTrademark - Signposts can look very different, but if they lead to the same place, they're duplicates. "London This Way' and "ロンドン・ディス・ウェイ" might look very different, but they mean the same thing.

These Q's don't say the same thing, unlike those signs. They are very different things that happen to lead to the same result. It's nice for posterity to have the different clues for those who would seek out the same thing. This Q is about traps and fighting robots and does not mention VR, the other Q doesn't mention traps, robots or the sewers.

@MeatTrademark - That's not how SE works. If the questions lead to the same answer, they're considered to be fundamentally the same question, regardless of how they're phrased.

@MeatTrademark This question was actually closed as a duplicate back in January 2016. The recent ID question restoration by the CMs seems to have reopened it, along with a few others that were previously closed and migrated to SF&F SE.
